# Is it possible to run indented blocks using exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Using the `exec()` python command, is it possible to run indented blocks of code (Like `if/else` statements or `try/except`). For example:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
if name == "Bob":
     print("Hi bob")
else:
     print("Hi user")
```

At the moment I am using this to run the code:

```
code_list = []
while True:
     code = input("Enter code or type end: ")
     if code == "end":
          break
     else:
          code_list.append(code)
for code_piece in code_list:
     exec(code_piece)
```

Also I know that this isn't very "Pythonic" or "Good practise" to let the user input their own code but it will be useful in other parts of my code.

Comment: Have you *tried* running indented code with `exec`? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here isn't the indentation. The problem is that you're trying to `exec` the lines of a compound statement one by one. Python can't make sense of a compound statement without the whole thing.

`exec` the whole input as a single unit:

```
exec('\n'.join(code_list))
```

Comment: Great, that fixed it.

Comment: Nice, that fixed it! @cattythegamer

Answer (score 0):

From [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) documentation:

> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. object must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed ...

Thus, you can do things like

```
exec("a=2\nb=3")
exec("if a==2:\n\tprint(a)\nelse:\tprint(b)")
```

You just need to follow the right syntax and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of formatting code within an exec() function is to use triple quotes, which makes it easy to see what the code looks like.

```
code = """                     # Opening quotes
for i in range(0, 10):         # Code line 1         
    print(i)                   # Code line 2
"""                            # Closing quotes
exec(code)
```

This would maybe not work if you're asking the user to input the code, but it's a trick that may come in handy.